# Connecting islands to the mainland via flood fill

Tags: algorithms, graphs, nearest-neighbour

Say I have a large area filled using floodfill: [image]

Where the area in white has been flooded, and all other ares are not connected. I would like to "bridge" these islands to the main area in white, but I'm not sure of the best algorithm to use that would do this most efficiently.

My current method is to find the nearest non-flooded valid space (that I'll call point $x$) to all grid squares, then use their distance as their priority in a priority queue, with smallest distance going first. I then destroy all walls in a straight line between the two with shortest distance, re-flood from point $x$, and after doing so examine all the newly flooded spaces and find their shortest distance to non-flooded areas, adding them to the priority queue. Repeating this until eventually there are no islands left.

Pseudo code below:

```
bridge_check = priority_queue()
for each space in flooded_area:
    dist, other_space = nearest_non_flooded(space)
    bridge_check.add(val=(space,other_space), priority=dist)
while(!bridge_check.isEmpty()):
    flooded, non_flooded = bridge_check.get()
    if non_flooded in flooded_area:
        continue
    remove_walls(flooded, non_flooded)
    newly_flooded = reflood(flooded_area, from=flooded)
    for each space in newly_flooded:
        dist, other_space = nearest_non_flooded(space)
        bridge_check.add(val=(space,other_space), priority=dist)
```

Comment: Perhaps you should color white everything which is not black?

Comment: Can you explain in more detail your goal, that is, what you are trying to accomplish? What does it mean to "bridge" islands? Why floodfill in particular?

Comment: What islands in particular are you referring to?